# How to start a MonoGame project for Windows desktop (and future port)?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, monogame

I want to open a new project in MonoGame, using Visual Studio Express 2012. I currently want to make it for Windows desktop.

The problem is there is no such setup in the "New project" menu. I don't want it to be for the Windows Store, there appears to be an option for that. Should I open an OpenGL project?

And how could I later take the same project and set it up for Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you can see the following options? The one you want is MonoGame Windows OpenGL Project. This will run on the normal windows desktop for XP, Windows 7 and Windows 8 Desktop mode I believe.

[image: MonoGame New Project Window]

As for the second part of your question. I'm not exactly sure of the details of porting to Linux but the general rule as that you create a new Linux project and link each file from your main project then recompile. You may need to change some code to deal with platform specific stuff.

Comment: Why do I need to use OpenGL? On XNA I never had to choose anything like that.

Comment: MonoGames is an open-source implementation of XNA makes sense to use an open-source graphics library. Xna is not open-sourced and used DirectX which is also not open-source.

Comment: Microsoft has dropped support for XNA in Windows 8 onwards but you can still use XNA for Windows 7 or earlier if you want. MonoGame is designed so you can take your XNA games to other platforms easily using mostly the same code. It also happens to support the Windows 8 Store. MonoGame currently supports the following platforms iOS, Android, Windows (both OpenGL and DirectX), Mac OS X, Linux, Windows 8 Store, Windows Phone 8, PlayStation Mobile and OUYA. However, I'm not sure if the DirectX support is stable so I would recommend sticking with OpenGL.